# Executing jar with relative path from script

Tags: java, relative-path, launchd

I'm trying to execute some Java code by using MacOS "scheduler" `launchd`.

My plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.nathangrigg.archive-tweets</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/ie54553/Desktop/MyProject/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/out.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/err.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

script.sh:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Users/ie54553/Desktop/MyProj/classes/artifacts/jarFile_jar/Application.jar
```

The problem is, all the relative path I've in my program (resources path, properties, logs location, spring bean files etc) are fail.

The plist file is located under the root folder, therefore I assume that all the paths are relative to the executor location.

Comment: The paths are relative to the current directory. You can change the current directory using cd command in the script.

Comment: the script.sh is located in the project's directory. the problem is that the plist file (the launchd configuration) is located under /Library/LaunchDaemons ..  and he is the one who start's the flow.

Comment: @lgal Current directory doesn't depend on where the script you're running is located. You just `cd` into any directory, so it becomes current, and then run any script in any other directory, and that script will work in the current directory.

Comment: What did you mean by "all of them are fail"?

Answer (score 0):

If the path starts with a '/' then its considered as an absolute path and treated as such. Is there a 'tmp' directory under '/' (and with write access) ? If not then try 'tmp' rather than '/tmp'.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) :

> For UNIX platforms, the prefix of an absolute pathname is always "/". Relative pathnames have no prefix. The abstract pathname denoting the root directory has the prefix "/" and an empty name sequence.